# Getting error on vis js events

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I'm building a timeline in `vue.js` app so I decided to use `vis.js` but I'm having problems with it when I want to add some events. First of all when i set `@drop="myDropCallback()"` and when I drop one item nothing happens so the function is not called but when i put `@mouseOver="myDropCallback()"` then it works, its strange.

Second when I'm doing the `mouseOver` event I want to get the event properties with `this.$refs.timeline.getEventProperties(event)` but I'm getting this error every time

> Error in event handler for "click": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'center' of undefined"

and this error

> Cannot read property 'center' of undefined

So does anyone know how to fix that? Or am I doing something wrong?

Template

```
<timeline v-if="items.length > 0" ref="timeline"
  :items="items"
  :groups="groups"
  :options="options"
  @drop="myDropCallback()">
</timeline>
```

Drop function

```
myDropCallback: function (event) {
  console.log('value', this.$refs.timeline.getEventProperties())
},
```

Picture of timeline

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an excerpt from the vis.js source. You'll notice that the first thing it tries to do is to find the event's center value.

```
Timeline.prototype.getEventProperties = function (event) {
  var clientX = event.center ? event.center.x : event.clientX;
  var clientY = event.center ? event.center.y : event.clientY;
  var x;
  if (this.options.rtl) {
    x = util.getAbsoluteRight(this.dom.centerContainer) - clientX;
  } else {
    x = clientX - util.getAbsoluteLeft(this.dom.centerContainer);
  }
  var y = clientY - util.getAbsoluteTop(this.dom.centerContainer);

  var item = this.itemSet.itemFromTarget(event);
  var group = this.itemSet.groupFromTarget(event);
  var customTime = CustomTime.customTimeFromTarget(event);

  var snap = this.itemSet.options.snap || null;
  var scale = this.body.util.getScale();
  var step = this.body.util.getStep();
  var time = this._toTime(x);
  var snappedTime = snap ? snap(time, scale, step) : time;

  var element = util.getTarget(event);
  var what = null;
  if (item != null) {
    what = 'item';
  } else if (customTime != null) {
    what = 'custom-time';
  } else if (util.hasParent(element, this.timeAxis.dom.foreground)) {
    what = 'axis';
  } else if (this.timeAxis2 && util.hasParent(element, this.timeAxis2.dom.foreground)) {
    what = 'axis';
  } else if (util.hasParent(element, this.itemSet.dom.labelSet)) {
    what = 'group-label';
  } else if (util.hasParent(element, this.currentTime.bar)) {
    what = 'current-time';
  } else if (util.hasParent(element, this.dom.center)) {
    what = 'background';
  }

  return {
    event: event,
    item: item ? item.id : null,
    group: group ? group.groupId : null,
    what: what,
    pageX: event.srcEvent ? event.srcEvent.pageX : event.pageX,
    pageY: event.srcEvent ? event.srcEvent.pageY : event.pageY,
    x: x,
    y: y,
    time: time,
    snappedTime: snappedTime
  };
};
```

So your issue is most likely due to not giving the method a valid event. I believe that this is because you aren't supplying any parameters to the getEventProperties method. I would try something like:

```
myDropCallback: function (event) {
  console.log('value', this.$refs.timeline.getEventProperties(event))
},
```

Also, here is a good stack overflow post answered by one of the authors of vis.js: [vis.js timeline how to add mouse over event to vis-item box-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967322/vis-js-timeline-how-to-add-mouse-over-event-to-vis-item-box-box)

Comment: So thats the getEventProperties function from vis.js? I tried to send event to the function bu I'm getting the same error.

Comment: When i remove the event from the brackets then I'm not getting any error and the getEventProperties is returning what I want. But thats on mouseOver, mouseLeave, click and etc. When I try to do the drop event then nothing happens. Did i need to write the drop event on my own or?

Comment: Here's another good example. http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/other/drag&drop.html Check out the sources tab in the developer tools and look at the source for drag&drop.html. It looks like you need to register dragstart event listeners on the items you are going to drag onto the timeline.